# Ubuntu 17.04 freezes while sleeping

Tags: ubuntu, amd-graphics, asus

I have a problem that has drove me nuts for too long, hopefully someone here can help.

When I attempt to put my system to sleep, seemingly randomly, it will look like it is in the process but will instead freeze to a black screen and my pc is still running fans, mobo lights are on, etc.

Anyone come across a similar issue?

`inxi -Fxz` shows:

```
System:    Host: desktop Kernel: 4.10.0-30-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 6.3.0)
           Desktop: MATE 1.18.0 (Gtk 3.22.11-0ubuntu3) Distro: Ubuntu 17.04
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: Crosshair V Formula v: Rev 1.xx
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1402 date: 04/19/2012
CPU:       Quad core AMD Phenom II X4 955 (-MCP-) cache: 2048 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4a svm) bmips: 25684
           clock speeds: max: 3210 MHz 1: 3210 MHz 2: 3210 MHz 3: 3210 MHz 4: 3210 MH
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480] bus-ID: 06:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.3 drivers: ati,amdgpu (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,radeon)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 1440x900@59.89hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD POLARIS10 (DRM 3.9.0 / 4.10.0-30-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Device aaf0 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 06:00.1
           Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:14.2
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-30-generic
Network:   Card: Intel 82583V Gigabit Network Connection driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: d000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 2064.4GB (4.5% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD20EARS size: 2000.4GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdc model: USB_Flash_Drive size: 64.0GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 1.8T used: 80G (5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 31.1C mobo: N/A gpu: 33.0
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 0
Info:      Processes: 218 Uptime: 4 min Memory: 1277.6/7942.2MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 6.3.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.71) inxi: 2.3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and adding the following to the kernel parameters solved the problem:

```
acpi_osi= acpi_backlight=vendor
```